# How to mock calls to function that receives mutable object as parameter?

Tags: python, mocking

Consider example:

```
def func_b(a):
    print a

def func_a():
    a = [-1]
    for i in xrange(0, 2):
        a[0] = i
        func_b(a)
```

And test function that tries to test func_a and mocks func_b:

```
import mock
from mock import call

def test_a():
    from dataTransform.test import func_a
    with mock.patch('dataTransform.test.func_b', autospec=True) as func_b_mock:
        func_a()
        func_b_mock.assert_has_calls([call(0), call(1)])
```

After func_a has executed I try to test if func_a made correct calls to func_b, but since in for loop I am mutating list in the end I get:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(0), call(1)]
Actual: [call([1]), call([1])]
```

Comment: Your mock of `func_b()` will need to make copies or otherwise untouchable representations of the argument it gets.  Then you can later check these copies for their values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i check call arguments if they will change with unittest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236870/how-can-i-check-call-arguments-if-they-will-change-with-unittest-mock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works (the importing `mock` from `unittest` is a Python 3 thing, and `module` is where `func_a` and `func_b` are):

```
import mock
from mock import call
import copy

class ModifiedMagicMock(mock.MagicMock):
    def _mock_call(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ModifiedMagicMock, _mock_self)._mock_call(*copy.deepcopy(args), **copy.deepcopy(kwargs))
```

This inherits from `MagicMock`, and redefines the call behaviour to deepcopy the arguments and keyword arguments.

```
def test_a():
    from module import func_a
    with mock.patch('module.func_b', new_callable=ModifiedMagicMock) as func_b_mock:
        func_a()
        func_b_mock.assert_has_calls([call([0]), call([1])])
```

You can pass the new class into `patch` using the `new_callable` parameter, however it cannot co-exist with `autospec`. Note that your function calls `func_b` with a list, so `call(0), call(1)` has to be changed to `call([0]), call([1])`. When run by calling `test_a`, this does nothing (passes).

Now we cannot use both `new_callable` and `autospec` because `new_callable` is a generic factory but in our case is just a `MagicMock` override. But [Autospeccing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) is a very cool `mock`'s feature, we don't want lose it.

What we need is replace `MagicMock` by `ModifiedMagicMock` just for our test: we want avoid to change `MagicMock` behavior for all tests... could be dangerous. We already have a tool to do it and it is `patch`, used with the `new` argument to replace the destination.

In this case we use decorators to avoid too much indentation and make it more readable:

```
@mock.patch('module.func_b', autospec=True)
@mock.patch("mock.MagicMock", new=ModifiedMagicMock)
def test_a(func_b_mock):
    from module import func_a
    func_a()
    func_b_mock.assert_has_calls([call([0]), call([1])])
```

Or:

```
@mock.patch("mock.MagicMock", new=ModifiedMagicMock)
def test_a():
    with mock.patch('module.func_b') as func_b_mock:
        from module import func_a
        func_a()
        func_b_mock.assert_has_calls([call([0]), call([1])])
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing to mention that in python 2.7 call to parent function would look like: 
        return super(ModifiedMagicMock, _mock_self)._mock_call(*copy.deepcopy(args), **kwargs)

Comment: Sorry, I forget it... And I wrote an answer about that some months ago☺.

Comment: I know a way to solve this leak. If you are agree I can edit your answer again, otherwise I can file a new answer to cover it. I hate to lose autospec feature.

Comment: @matsjoyce Can I use decorators instead of with statements... it is more redable.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Thanks. For some reason (mocking being clever), it only worked when I reversed the order of the decorators. I added a half `with` half decorator version, just in case the implementation of mocking changes.

Comment: @matsjoyce Is not mock implementation dependent, but it is how decorators stack works. My fault was that I used pycharm to execute it but it was not a unitettest class and pass without test anything... Decorators are just syntactic sugar where a stack of two decorators (i.e. `d1` and `d2`) applied to `f` means `f=d1(d2(f))` so the last decorator is applied as first.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico No, it is patching. Assuming decorators work like normal decorators, they stack like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python. However, when multiple patch decorators are applied to a function, mocking keeps a list, which it appends the new patch to. However, the patches are patched starting from the start of the list, so the last decorator is executed first.

Comment: @matsjoyce If you read well the answer that you post you will see that it explain exactly what I said. And ... exactly, decorators starts  from the first but evaluation of a functors start from evaluate arguments :) .... follow the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and you will read exactly what I wrote. Pay attention! `@patch()` don't execute `_patch.__call__` until decorator is evaluated... finally the list of patches is not reversed. I guess that implementation is to have a simple way to rollback if something goes wrong in patch stacks.

Comment: @matsjoyce I'm very nice to meet you. You are a fine programmer that goes deep to understand the details.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Thanks! I would reply in the comments, but the code examples are too long, so could you see https://gist.github.com/matsjoyce/30695312d57a901b25cf#file-reply-md. I'm still sure mocking is to blame for the 'wrong' order.

Comment: Ok, you win... Too much beer yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a section on this topic in the Python docs with multiple proposed workarounds: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#coping-with-mutable-arguments