# mock doesn't work in objects on kwargs

Tags: python, mocking

It seems that the kwarg assignment is not getting mocked in the mock.patch, but if it's called inside a function, it is.

Any ideas?

```
import platform
import mock


def test(arch=platform.machine()):
    print "arch = %s" % arch
    print "machine = %s" % platform.machine()

with mock.patch.object(platform, "machine", return_value="TEST"):
    test()


# This outputs
# arch = x86_64
# machine = TEST
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i check call arguments if they will change with unittest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236870/how-can-i-check-call-arguments-if-they-will-change-with-unittest-mock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function defaults are set and stored with the function object when the function definition is executed.

Mocking `platform.machine` works fine, but the default value for the `arch` argument has long since been set by calling `platform.machine()` and using the return value. The expression is *not* used when `test()` is called.

See ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941) for why that is.

You'll need to patch `platform` *before* you ever import the module that defines the function; you could move the function to a new module, and do this:

```
import sys

if 'modulename' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['modulename']  # ensure the cached module is cleared

with mock.patch.object(platform, "machine", return_value="TEST"):
    from modulename import sys
    test()

del sys.modules['modulename']  # clear the module with the mocked value again
```

This is rather cumbersome and will fail if you were to run tests in threads.

You can use `None` as the default instead and create the default when `test` is called instead:

```
def test(arch=None):
    if arch is None:
        arch = platform.machine()
    print "arch = %s" % arch
    print "machine = %s" % platform.machine()
```